# MSI Installer fails with error :Assembly Error:The parameter is incorrect

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have created an MSI installer using Wix toolset (version 3.11) and the installer works fine on all other servers. But **on AWS instances with OS, Windows server 2012 R2 installer fails** with error `Assembly Error:The parameter is incorrect.`

Installer verbose log file lines which i felt are related to this error are below (complete log can not be attached)

```
MSI (s) (88:8C) [08:50:05:010]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (s) (88:8C) [08:50:05:010]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (s) (88:8C) [08:50:05:010]: Set LastUsedSource to: C:\Users\Shreesha.Rao\Desktop\18.0.2\.
MSI (s) (88:8C) [08:50:05:010]: Set LastUsedType to: n.
MSI (s) (88:8C) [08:50:05:010]: Set LastUsedIndex to: 1.
MSI (s) (88:8C) [08:50:05:010]: Executing op: End(Checksum=0,ProgressTotalHDWord=0,ProgressTotalLDWord=5851241)
06/29/2018 08:50:05.041 [3720]: Assembly Install: Failing with hr=80070057 at CAssemblyCacheItem::MoveAssemblyToFinalLocation, line 846

06/29/2018 08:50:05.041 [3720]: Assembly Install: Failing with hr=80070057 at CAssemblyCacheItem::LegacyCommit, line 1444

MSI (s) (88:8C) [08:50:05:041]: Assembly Error:The parameter is incorrect.

MSI (s) (88:8C) [08:50:05:041]: Note: 1: 1935 2: {6E5EE8E5-86C6-4E4E-BF86-0FF21C02E57A} 3: 0x80070057 4: IAssemblyCacheItem 5: Commit 6: [assemblyname],version="1.1.14.0",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="13D9421F3DD97943",processorArchitecture="MSIL" 
MSI (s) (88:8C) [08:50:05:041]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (88:8C) [08:50:05:041]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1935 
MSI (s) (88:8C) [08:50:28:899]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (88:8C) [08:50:28:899]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (s) (88:8C) [08:50:28:899]: Product: [product] 18.0.6 -- Error 1935. An error occurred during the installation of assembly '[assemblyname],version="1.1.14.0",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="13D9421F3DD97943",processorArchitecture="MSIL"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80070057. assembly interface: IAssemblyCacheItem, function: Commit, component: {6E5EE8E5-86C6-4E4E-BF86-0FF21C02E57A}

06/29/2018 08:50:28.899 [3720]: Assembly Install: Failing with hr=80070005 at RemoveDirectoryAndChildren, line 393
```

I have tried,

- verifying if the user is an admin : User is administrator
- Disabled 'User Account Control : Run all administrators in Admin Approval
  Mode' from Local Security Policy (followed a [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mossbiz/2010/06/10/add-an-assembly-to-the-global-assembly-cache-on-windows-server-2008-r2/))
- Searched for the error number 1935 : did not get any useful information

Please help me.

Note:I am not sure this error is related to MSI or Wix toolset ( i am 90% sure error is not related to wix toolset) so adding both the tags.

Comment: What architecture is the install?

Comment: @PhilDW It is 64 bit installer.

Comment: I should have asked a more detailed question: Some Server OS versions are completely 64-bit only and have no 32-bit subsystem. Trying to install 32-bit assemblies on these systems might get this error.

Comment: No @PhilDW, I have verified again and the installer is 64 bit.

Comment: I asked about the architecture of the assemblies in my most recent question. Again, some Server OS versions do not have a 32-bit subsystem, so 32-bit assemblies cannot be installed in the GAC.

Comment: @PhilDW, assembly architecture is 'Any CPU'. When i install the installer on working servers, assemblies are installed into GAC_MSIL .